# raw_interfaces_only usage?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, com

Can somebody please explain what raw_interfaces_only actually does?

For Example,

```
#import <xyz.dll> raw_interfaces_only
```

I am unable to understand the one liner explanation [provided in the msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/298h7faa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @RomanR. What he means is, it is not standard C++

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds25e53):

> Suppresses the generation of error-handling wrapper functions and property (C++) declarations that use those wrapper functions.

and

> The raw_interfaces_only attribute also causes the default prefix used
>   in naming the non-property functions to be removed. Normally, the
>   prefix is raw_. If this attribute is specified, the function names are
>   directly from the type library.
>
> This attribute allows you to expose only the low-level contents of the
>   type library.

You can also build with and without this attribute, and compare produced `.tlh` files to see the difference:

```
#import <imapi2.dll> // --> imapi2-without.tlh
#import <imapi2.dll> raw_interfaces_only // --> imapi2-with.tlh
```

[image]

The `raw_interfaces_only` attribute causes generation of less wrapper code.

Comment: Diff the `.tli` files too. There's a lot of "junk" in it when not using raw interfaces (converting HRESULTs to _com_error exceptions).

Comment: The `raw_interfaces_only` attribute causes **zero** wrapper code to be generated. Using this attribute, the `#import` directive will not generate a corresponding .tli file (containing the wrapper code implementations).

Comment: In my case,    raw_interfaces_only keyword causes some methods to require more arguments. Ex, Load_3 of mscorlib::_AppDomainPtr will need 2 arguments instead of just one in case no raw_interfaces_only supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking a look at the first reasult from Google, [lazy link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it appears to be an 'attribute'

form that page:

```
#import  "filename" [attributes]
#import  <filename> [attributes]
```

we can then read for ourselves what the [raw_interfaces_only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#_predir_raw_interfaces_only) attribute does:

> The raw_interfaces_only attribute suppresses the generation of error-handling wrapper functions and __declspec(property) declarations that use those wrapper functions.

Which sounds to me like a simple case of, it helps reduce to mess from importing a library, less wrapper code and error checking done for you.